# Como verificar corretamente o status de um Checkbox em js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

Preciso de uma funcionalidade em que os *Checkbox* estejam aninhados entre si.
Dessa forma, o elemento pai selecionaria todos os filhos e assim por diante.

**Minha lógica foi a seguinte:**

> Como vou receber esses dados externamente, eu consigo manipular os *ids* e as *class* desse *checkbox*
>   Assim, se eu criar uma classe *pai* que tem em todos os atributos que receberão essa funcionalidade e concatenar uma *class específica* aos filhos, eu tenho uma relação entre os dois.

Exemplo: o elemento cujo a *class*  é **pai** e o id é *idPai*, teria uma relaçao a todos os *checkbox* cujo a *class* seja **filhoidPai**

Essa é a estrutura do HTML que eu utilizei:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input pai" type="checkbox" id="idPai">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Checkbox exemplo
            </label>
        </div>
        <ul style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; list-style: none;">
            <li>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input filhoidPai"  type="checkbox" id="idOption1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Checkbox exemplo
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input filhoidPai" type="checkbox" id="idOption2">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Checkbox exemplo
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Nesse código vemos que o **idPai** tem a *class* **pai**, portanto ele controla o estado de todos que tem o seu nome (nesse casso, todos os **filhoidPai**). 
Dessa forma, para esse problema o script abaixo atende a minha situação:

```js
$(".pai").on("change", function (e) {
    var select = ".filho" + $(this).attr("id")


    var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');

    $(select).each(function (e) {
        $(this).prop("checked", isChecked);
    })
});
```

**Porém** (é ai que vem a dúvida), quando eu tento adicionar mais um nível nessa hierarquia (ou seja, um pai que também é filho), as coisas ficam um pouco diferentes...

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input pai" type="checkbox" id="idPai">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Checkbox exemplo
            </label>
        </div>
        <ul style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; list-style: none;">
            <li>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input filhoidPai"  type="checkbox" id="idOption1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Checkbox exemplo
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input filhoidPai pai" type="checkbox" id="idOption2">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Checkbox exemplo
                    </label>
                </div>
                <ul style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; list-style: none;">
                    <li>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input filhoidOption2" type="checkbox" id="idOption2SubOption">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                                Checkbox exemplo
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Ao meu ver, a função *change* alteraria o status de **todos os *checkbox* na hierarquia**, coisa que não acontece.

Quando o **idPai** é acionado, automaticamente todos os **filhoidPai** são acionados também (inclusive o que é filho e pai). Da mesma forma que quando o **idOption2** é acionado, todos os **filhoidOption2** também são. O problema é que quando **idPai** for selecionado, eu queria que eles acionasse tanto os *filhos* quanto os *filhos dos filhos*, tornando-a, uma função recursiva.
Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há algumas formas:

- Adicionar a classe `idPai` nos netos. Ex: `class="form-check-input filhoidOption2 idPai"`; ou
- Usar uma classe com o nome que possua todos os níveis.

  > Ex: `class="pai"`, `class="filho-1"`, `class="filho-2"`, `class="filho-1-1"` (neto)
- Percorrer todos os `input:checkbox` com a função `.find`

Optei fazer um exemplo usando este método. Para isso, usei a função `.parents()` para retornar ao elemento pai `.form-check` e, logo após, utilizei o método `next` para ele pegar o elemento `ul` irmão.

Como a estrutura é sempre `(div.form-check > input:check) + ul`, vai funcionar corretamente. Com isso, podemos usar o método `.find()` para buscar os *input:checkbox* daquele pai específico.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(".pai").on("change", function(e) {
  var filhos = $(this)
    .parents('.form-check') /** Seleciona o elemento pai `.form-check` */
    .next('ul') /** Busca o elemento `ul` irmão do pai */
    .find('input:checkbox') /** Seleciona todos os `input` do tipo `checkbox` */
  
  var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');

  $(filhos).each(function(e) {
    $(this).prop("checked", isChecked);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">Checkbox</div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input pai" type="checkbox" id="idPai">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                Checkbox exemplo (Pai)
            </label>
    </div>
    <ul style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; list-style: none;">
      <li>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input filhoidPai" type="checkbox" id="idOption1">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Checkbox exemplo (Filho)
                    </label>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input filhoidPai pai" type="checkbox" id="idOption2">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                        Checkbox exemplo (Pai e Filho)
                    </label>
        </div>
        <ul style="display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; list-style: none;">
          <li>
            <div class="form-check">
              <input class="form-check-input filhoidOption2" type="checkbox" id="idOption2SubOption">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck1">
                                Checkbox exemplo (Neto e Filho)
                            </label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse procedimento funciona se eu criar uma nova hieraquia de checkbox? (ou seja, o próximo pai interfirirá nos filhos do outro pai?)

Comment: E eu sei que isso não é mais pertinente a minha pergunta, mas tem como desmarcar o pai ao ter todos os filhos desmarcados? E se sim, há alguma forma de ao marcar um filho, ele encontre o pai e o marque também?

Comment: @WalterFelipe Funciona com diversos níveis de hierarquia, desde que tenham a mesma estrutura (expliquei-a no 3º parágrafo). Também é possível marcar o pai ao marcar o filho e vice-versa, mas isso foge da pergunta principal. Recomendo que crie outra com as novas dúvidas. Caso contrário a moderação do site poderá reverter sua pergunta para a original.